# Azure API deployment issue - Swashbuckle SwaggenGen Error

Tags: c#, azure, swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've got a problem when trying to deploy my App Service to Azure from VS 2022. Each time I'm getting this error:

[image: Deployment error]

I'm using .NET 6 as my target framework and I've got the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package updated to the newest version. The app service is published with success, but the error pops up when trying to update the API.

In my version of the project there is no Startup.cs but Program.cs, and the way I'm implementing the Swagger generation is:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

I've browsed through similar posts and based on them I can add that I am not fetching any environment variables too.

I've also tried using `UseSwaggerUI()` like this but I get the same error anyway:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

Weird thing is that the deployment works for my colleague and it worked for me until last week when it stopped when nothing in the Program.cs was changed on the way.

My Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var azureKeyVaultUrl = builder.Configuration[AppConfigurationConst.AzureKeyVaultUrl];
var logAnalyticsWorkspaceId = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetAzureKeyVault(azureKeyVaultUrl, AppConfigurationConst.LogAnalyticsWorkspaceId);
var logAnaliticsAuthenticationId = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetAzureKeyVault(azureKeyVaultUrl, AppConfigurationConst.LogAnaliticsAuthenticationId);
var CrmConnectionString = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetAzureKeyVault(azureKeyVaultUrl, AppConfigurationConst.OneCrmConnectionString);

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .WriteTo.AzureAnalytics(logAnalyticsWorkspaceId, logAnaliticsAuthenticationId)
               .Enrich.FromLogContext()
               .CreateLogger();

var serviceClient = new ServiceClient(CrmConnectionString);


builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

logger.Information("Start ALGOI App Service");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWebClientService, WebClientService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICreateSessionService, CreateSessionService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICreateFolderService, CreateFolderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDeleteFolderService, DeleteFolderService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IVerifyFolderService, VerifyFolderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUndoFolderService, UndoFolderService>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(serviceClient);
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();


app.Run();
```

And my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>{usersecretsid}</UserSecretsId>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>True</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Connected Services\**" />
    <Content Remove="Connected Services\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Connected Services\**" />
    <None Remove="Connected Services\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JsonSubTypes" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.34.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.48.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client" Version="1.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.AzureAnalytics" Version="4.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="TypeSafe.Http.Net.HttpClient" Version="2.2.16" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="someprojectpath" />
    <ProjectReference Include="someprojectpath" />
    <ProjectReference Include="someprojectpath" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain",
    "TenantId": "tenantid",
    "ClientId": "clientid",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "Client secret from app-registration. Check user secrets/azure portal.",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AzureKeyVaultUrl": "keyvaulturl",
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "appinsightsconnectionstring"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I've found out that the cause of the error are those lines:

```
var azureKeyVaultUrl = builder.Configuration[AppConfigurationConst.AzureKeyVaultUrl];
var logAnalyticsWorkspaceId = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetAzureKeyVault(azureKeyVaultUrl, AppConfigurationConst.LogAnalyticsWorkspaceId);
var logAnaliticsAuthenticationId = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetAzureKeyVault(azureKeyVaultUrl, AppConfigurationConst.LogAnaliticsAuthenticationId);
var CrmConnectionString = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetAzureKeyVault(azureKeyVaultUrl, AppConfigurationConst.OneCrmConnectionString);
```

I've since changed them to get values directly from configuration instead of keyvault:

```
var azureKeyVaultUrl = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>(AppConfigurationConst.AzureKeyVaultUrl);
var logAnalyticsWorkspaceId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>(AppConfigurationConst.LogAnalyticsWorkspaceId);
var logAnaliticsAuthenticationId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>(AppConfigurationConst.LogAnaliticsAuthenticationId);
var CrmConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>(AppConfigurationConst.OneCrmConnectionString);
```

When running locally, it takes the values correctly and assignes them to the variables. But it seems that when deploying it encounters a problem with that. In line `var serviceClient = new ServiceClient(CrmConnectionString);` when I change the variable to static string it works correctly, but when using the variable the startup.cs error pops up (only when deploying). Same thing with initializing logger which uses the log analitycs values. Again, locally runs with no problems, only the deployment crashes.

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` file once.

Comment: Also please share your complete `Program.cs` file once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample `ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API` and able to deploy the Application to `Azure App Service` without any errors.

Generally, this type of error occurs when there is any error in the code or Configuration issues.

> In my version of the project there is no Startup.cs but Program.cs

***`.Net6 Core` Folder Structure:***

[image]

Yes, we need to `Configure` the code related to `Swagger` in `Program.cs` itself.

Check the below steps and make sure you are following the same to deploy without any issues.

- Select the `ASP.NET Core Web API` template.
  [image]
- Select `Enable openAPI support`.
  [image]

***My `.csproj` file :***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My `Program.cs` file :***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***Output of Deployed Azure App Service:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is basically what I've done on this project, but my .csproj and Program.cs are more extensive. I've added them to the post.

Comment: @Dario - Ok will work on it and let you know. Will check with your code once.

Comment: Please share your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: added appsettings.json

Comment: You are adding `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` to builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry.Is it working locally?

Comment: I think it has to be `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING` not `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING`. Please check once.

Comment: The configuration option for app insights connection string is in accordance to the one on the app service in Azure and it's correct. The app is building locally, only throws the error when deploying

Comment: I've updated the question, the problem seems to be with extracting values from the configuration.

Comment: Yes,I have already mentioned the point in the 2nd line in my answer.