# Issue publishing ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure (.NET 6, Swagger)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

The output shows that the web app was published successfully, but throws this error when updating the API to generate the swagger file.

[image: Error during publish]

> Publish has encountered an error. Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file. Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131205&clcid=0x409 for more information.

**What I tried**

I added the following swagger doc configuration to the `AddSwaggerGen` in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
  {
    Title = "MyAPI",
    Version = "v1"
  });
});
```

Published again and got the same error. I then created a new API for testing, it published just fine. Apart from the obvious, the main difference was that my original API was using the .NET 6 target framework and the new API for testing was set to use .NET 7. So I updated my original API to use .NET 7 as well. Tried publishing again and it worked without issue.

However, the `azurewebsites.net` site the opened up after the successful publish wasn't showing the swagger documentation as I expected. 404 not found. I checked that Swashbuckle was up-to-date. Sure enough, it was the latest version (6.5.0).

After some searching, I realized that I needed to define the `UseSwaggerUI` options for my production environment. The Microsoft tutorial that I had started with suggested moving the `UseSwagger` middleware definition outside of the development environment check since we always want to set that (not just in the development environment), like this:

```
app.UseSwagger();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

BUT what you need to do is also define the `SwaggerEndpoint` for your production as well. So what I ended up with is:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
  {
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
  });
}
```

Now, when I published again, no only did the publish succeed, but my specific `azurewebsites.net` site defaulted to the swagger documentation like I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### **TL;DR:**

To fix the issue I

- updated from .NET 6 to .NET 7
- defined the swagger documentation in `AddSwaggerGen` (this may not have been necessary)

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
  {
    Title = "MyAPI",
    Version = "v1"
  });
});
```

- defined the swagger endpoint for production

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
  {
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75297594/azure-api-deployment-issue-swashbuckle-swaggengen-error

Comment: For the consideration of security practitioners, the exposure of your swagger UI to the public is forfeiting the benefit of making guessing the only way to learn. You're giving the instructions to interface with your services, including those interfaces that may expose bigger gaps in security.